# QTP 11 Extensibility developing (.NET sdk) - calling Record() on the recorder object fails

Tags: sdk, automated-tests, qtp, recording

As far as I looked, there's no answered question about QTP's Ext. sdk on stackoverflow (and almost anywhere else on the net; there isn't even a appropriated tag for it...), so I'm aware it's unlikely I get my problem solved by asking , but whatever, it worth trying.

Anyway, before I lose the attention of anyone who never heard or used the Ext. sdk, maybe I will have more luck asking you to help me figure out how to locate the error log file QTP produces at run-time. I know such a file exists in the new UFT 11.5 version, but I couldn't locate it in QTP 10 or 11 (For the record, I don't talk about QTP's Log Tracking feature, but about the "meta" error log of errors/exceptions produced by QTP itself).

Now for the question:
I'm developing an extension for QTP to support native record and run tests on my application.
I'm currently able to import an object repository, and write test steps using The COM object testing agent I developed.
Problem started when I was trying to implement the IRecordable interface; I'm getting the IRecorder object from qtp, and even able to use it as ISuppressor object to exclude redundant steps from being recorded, but all my attempts to record a step (that is, to add new recorded objects to the repository, and add steps to the test) simply failed.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
public class MyTestingAgent :
    AutInterface.ITestable, 
    AutInterface.IRecordable
{
    QTPInterface.IRecorder recorder;
    ...

    public void AutInterface.IRecordable.BeginRecording(object recorder)
    {
        IRecordSuppressor recordSuppressor = recorder as IRecordSuppressor;
        recordSuppressor.Suppress(MyTestingAgentId, 
            "<Suppress><Item type=\"HWND\" value=\"[@HWND]\" /></Suppress>".Replace("[@HWND]", getMyAppHWND().ToString()));

        this.recorder = recorder as QTPInterface.IRecorder;
        ...
    }

    public void recordNewObjStep(string parentName, string objName, string method, Object[] arguments) 
    {
        object[] objectHyrarchy = new object[] { findObjectId(objName), findObjectId(parentName) };
        string externalParent = null;
        string appDescriptionXml = getDescriptionXml(parentName, objName);
        try
        {
            recorder.Record(MyTestingAgentId, objectHyrarchy , appDescriptionXml, externalParent, method, arguments);
            Trace.TraceInformation("Record successfully done.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("TEAAgent.recordSTElement: " + e.ToString());
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm pretty sure all the arguments I send with the call to Record() are accurate. getDescriptionXml() and findObjectId() are used in different cases in the code, and works fine, the method name and argument are correct.

The annoying thing is that the call to Record doesn't even throw exception, and I get "Record successfully done." in the trace log. Needless to say no new object is created in the repository, and no step is added to the test.

As I can't debug QTP, I'm pretty much in the dark with what I'm doing wrong. That's why I'm asking for help with finding QTP's log file, or any other approach that might shed some light on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

For QTP 11 you can turn on the logs by going to QTP's bin directory and running **ClientLogs.exe**.

Specifically for TEA extensibility do the following.

1. select the **QTP** node from the list on the left
2. find the *LogCatPackTEA* from the **Available Categories** list
3. Click the <kbd>></kbd> button to move it to Selected Categories
4. Change TEAs level to *Debug2* by selecting the category and changing the level
5. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and run QTP

The logs will show up as **QTP.log** in the diretory specified in **Path:**

I'm curious on what the problem you're facing is, please update if you find the cause.

[image: Screen shot]